# How can I change the .android path in Android Studio?

Tags: android, ide

I want to change the path of the .android and .gradle files. I already changed the settings to the path I want (E:\sdk)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0VUS.png

And add a new variable:
ANDROID_SDK_HOME
E:\sdk

But everytime I open the Android Studio, a new .android is created on the C:\Users\Client instead on E:\sdk.